# Get path of required module in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I have 2 classes, one that extends from the other. I need to have a method that can be called from extending classes but resolves the path to reflect whatever directory the extending class module is in.

/main.js

```
class Main {

   getTemplate () {
    return readFileSync(__dirname + './template.ejs')
   } 
}
```

/some/path/module.js (also contains /some/path/template.ejs)

```
class Module extends Main {

}
```

In main code

```
const m = new Module()
m.getTemplate() //  /some/path/template.ejs
```

The above doesn't work since __dirname doesn't reflect the 'module.js' path.

I've played around with `require.resolve` but I am not sure how I can use this from within the module.

Answer (score 0):

/main.js

```
class Main {
   constructor(dirname) {
     this.dirname = dirname;
   }

   getTemplate () {
    return readFileSync(this.dirname + './template.ejs')
   } 
}
```

/some/path/module.js (also contains /some/path/template.ejs)

```
class Module extends Main {
    constructor() {
      super(__dirname);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am doing something similar now. However I would like to do so without having to call the constructor if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I've got a working alas hokey solution.

```
class Main {
  constructor () {
    try {
      throw new Error()
    } catch(e) {
      const m = e.stack.match(/at new \w+ \(([^:]+)/)
      this.dirname = path.dirname(m[1])
    }
  }


  getTemplate () {
    return readFileSync(this.dirname + '/template.ejs')
  }     
}


class Module extends Main {

}
```